# formatting HTML content into a printable report

Tags: .net, html, crystal-reports, activereports

I have been using the AJAX html editor to create content for a .NET project. The content is stored as raw HTML mark-ups.  Now I need to take that content and inject it into a printable format.  I've tried report writers like Crystal Reports and/or ActiveReports. Both make references that it can consume HTML, but only a subset is processed. (ex: bold markups **work**, Spans with style setting don't)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I have found is to print it via the webbrowser control.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3.aspx

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If licensing software is a possibility, have had some luck with BCL easyPDF SDK.  Can output html to a printable pdf.  Internally I believe it uses the rendering engine of a browser.  Although, in my experience it's not always perfect.

[easyPdf SDK](http://www.pdfonline.com/easypdf/sdk/)

Comment: How are you printing the PDF? And can you change the print settings (margins, orientation, quality, etc)?

Comment: We're generating the PDFs from a VB6 EXE pulling data via odbc.  The SDK does have some flexibility around margins, etc... but we've used the default behavior.  

Here's the SDK documentation if it helps...
http://www.pdfonline.com/easypdf/epsdk_manual/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Rob:

Please send a couple examples of the actual HTML that you need processed to the [ActiveReports support forums](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/82/ShowForum.aspx) or to our support email address (support@grapecity.us.com) and the team will look into adding the additional HTML elements that you need processed to ActiveReports. I can't make any commitments until we see it, but the Product Manager will give it consideration.

```
Scott Willeke
US Tools Division Group Program Manager
GrapeCity
```

Comment: Let me know when you have sent an example to us and I'll follow up on it.

Comment: Scott:  I've sent an email to support@grapecity.us.com as you requested. Under the title: "Stackoverflow discussion - HTML Support in reporting"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, traveling right now. I member of the support team replied to you. I didn't like the reply, so I'm going to talk to the Product Manager directly and dig into it a bit more. We'll follow up with you in email.